# AJAX form going to PHP script instead of submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm attempting to use AJAX to post a simple insert query to the database; however, I'm using a while loop to generate multiple PHP forms which seems to be causing problems. I use the same class for all the html forms, and I've been attempting to use the live function in AJAX but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm just wondering how to insert this data asynchronously.

Thanks for the help.

**PHP**

```
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>  
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='moduleform'>
                <table id="t01">
                <tr><th colspan="3" id='upmost'>
    <?php
                echo 'Module Name: ' . $row['modulename'];
                $innermodname = $row['modulename'];

                echo "</th><th id='upmost'>";
                echo 'CAT Amount: ' . $row['catamount'];
    ?>
                </th></tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Mark Name</th>
                    <th>Mark Achieved</th>
                    <th>Mark Percentage</th>
                    <th>Comments</th>
                </tr>
    <?php

                $innerquery2 = "SELECT moduleid FROM modules WHERE modulename='$innermodname'";

                if (!$result2 = $db->query($innerquery2)) {
                    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
                }

                while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $ninnermodid = $row2['moduleid'];
                }

                $queryinner2 = "SELECT * FROM minimodules WHERE listid='$ninnermodid'";

                if (!$innerresult = $db->query($queryinner2)) {
                    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
                }

                while ($innerrow = $innerresult->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr><td>";
                    echo $innerrow['markname'];
                    echo "</td><td>";
                    echo $innerrow['markachieved'];
                    echo "</td><td>";
                    echo $innerrow['markpercentage'];
                    echo "</td><td>";
                    echo $innerrow['comments'];
                    echo "</td></tr>";
                }

    ?>

            </table>

            <form action='createmark.php' method='post' name='markform'>
                <input name='markname' placeholder='Result Name' maxlength='30'>
                <input name='markachieved' placeholder='Mark Achieved (0 if still to take)' maxlength='4'>
                <input name='markpercentage' step='1' placeholder='Percentage Of Module' maxlength='3' type='number'>
                <input name='comments' placeholder='Comments' maxlength='55'>
                <input name='hiddenid' value='<?php echo $ninnermodid; ?>' type='hidden'>
                <input type="submit" name="submit2" value='Add Mark' class='submit2'>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php

    }
```

**AJAX**

```
   $('document').ready(function() {

       $('.submit2').click(function() { 

             var markname = $('markname').val();
             var markachieved = $('markachieved').val();
             var markpercentage = $('markpercentage').val();
             var comments = $('comments').val();
             var hiddenid = $('hiddenid').val();

             $.ajax({

                url:        'createmark.php',
                type:       'POST',
                dataType:   'json',
                data:       '&markname=' + markname + '&markachieved=' + markachieved + '&markpercentage=' + markpercentage + '&comments=' + comments +'&hiddenid=' + hiddenid

             });         

            return false;

       });
    });
```

**PHP Script to Insert to DB**

```
$markname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['markname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
$markachieved = htmlspecialchars($_POST['markachieved'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
$markpercentage = htmlspecialchars($_POST['markpercentage'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
$comments = htmlspecialchars($_POST['comments'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
$hiddenid = htmlspecialchars($_POST['hiddenid'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');

$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO minimodules VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('isiisi', $minimodulesid, $markname, $markachieved, $markpercentage, $comments, $hiddenid);
$minimodulesid = 'NULL';
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: `.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and removed in 1.9. If you need event delegation, you should use `.on()`.

Comment: Use `$(this).serialize()` to get all the fields in the form.

Comment: What's the actual error?  In what specific way does this fail?  One thing I notice is your selectors are wrong: `$('markname')`  That's going to look for `<markname>` elements, which don't exist.

Comment: The first form has the AJAX functionality but any following forms will load the PHP script. The data will still be inserted into the database but it means the page has to be refreshed

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problems? You can also view the response by creating a `success` callback in the ajax.
Also, you should be watching the form element, not the submit button. That way, you can do `e.preventDefault()` to keep the form from submitting, and use jquery's `.serialize()` to get all of the form data instead of doing it manually.

Comment: @Fatboyover: `"The first form has the AJAX functionality but any following forms will load the PHP script."` - What does that even mean?  Can you clarify exactly what's happening?

Comment: @David Ok so from the while loop that generates the multiple html forms, when these are loaded onto the page, the first html form that is loaded, when submitted, will post the data asynchronously. However, any further html forms that are generated by the loop, when submitted, will take me to the 'createmark.php' script, as a blank page. The data will still be submitted to the database though

Comment: @Fatboyover: So if the loop creates 5 forms on the page... The first one posts via AJAX but the other 4 post normally?  Can you show the HTML/JavaScript that's being generated on the page?  It sounds like the jQuery click handler isn't being attached to the "other 4" buttons correctly.

Comment: @David the html generated on each page is the same as the form at the bottom of the PHP header, with the only thing being changed on each form being the hidden value

Comment: @Fatboyover: What do you mean "on each page"?  This isn't one page of `<form>` elements?  I'm sorry, but it's really not clear to me at all what you're describing here.  Please be complete and concise in your descriptions.

Comment: @David ah sorry, I just mean that for each form generated in the while loop, so from this screenshot the forms below the table https://gyazo.com/fc85e76689d2afebf9ff544e10b41d3d

Comment: @Fatboyover: So is my understand correct?  In a single page with (for example) 5 `<form>` elements, the first one successfully posts via AJAX but the remaining 4 post normally?  If that's the case, please provide a minimal and complete example of the HTML/JavaScript which behaves like this.

Comment: Do try and use prepared statements with placeholder values like you did in your last example. **DO NOT** use `htmlspecialchars` on your input, the `bind_param` call will take care of escaping as necessary.

Comment: @David yeah that's exactly what it's currently doing, not sure how to provide any more code than currently posted however, as all the code being used is posted above :/

Comment: @Fatboyover: Well, not to put too fine a point on it, but if the problem is manifesting in the client-side code (HTML and JavaScript) then you might at least want to *look* at the client-side code to make sure it's what you expect it to be.  Just looking at the server-side code which generates the client-side code and assuming it all went to plan isn't really the ideal approach.  Use your browser's debugging tools and see what the generated HTML/JavaScript is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all wrong:

```
         var markname = $('markname').val();
         var markachieved = $('markachieved').val();
         var markpercentage = $('markpercentage').val();
         var comments = $('comments').val();
         var hiddenid = $('hiddenid').val();
```

First, `$('markname')` is a selector that looks for an HTML element like `<markname>`. To find an input with `name="markname"`, it should be `$('input[name=markname]')`.

Second, you need to restrict the selector to the form that's being submitted, so it should be `$(this).find('input[name=markname]')`.

jQuery provides a function that finds all the input fields in a form, and gets all their values in the form needed for `$.ajax`: `$(this).serialize()`. So the code should be:

```
   $('.submit2').click(function() { 
         var data = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax({
            url:        'createmark.php',
            type:       'POST',
            dataType:   'json',
            data:       data
         });         
        return false;
   });
```